# Three.js custom shader not displaying

Tags: three.js, textures, shader, codepen

I recently started learning about shaders and three.js. I tried to display a shader with a texture but it displays all black.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/LDB95/pen/MxmWNq

These are my uniforms:

```
uniforms: {
tDiffuse: { value: null },
time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
iChannel0: { type: 't', value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://naqyr37xcg93tizq734pqsx1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/10-Things-We-Can-Learn-From-the-Incredible-Steve-Jobs.jpg')},
iChannel1: { type: 't', value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://gobelmont.ca/Portals/0/xBlog/uploads/2018/8/30/white%20noise.jpg')},
```

},

I just can't seem to find the fix. Would be really awesome if someone could help me out here :)

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [Migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide), Three.js version 102 changed the way to render to `RenderTarget`s, so the EffectComposer and ShaderPass in the examples might be outdated. For simplicity's sake, you should just import Three.js version 100 for now, until those examples are updated. Additionally, if you look at your console, you're getting a `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` warning. Your images are not being loaded. You should do a search on what that warning means to find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your codepen is full of mistakes. It seems you are trying to port a shader from shadertoy to `three.js`, right?

I have removed all errors here but the effect still looks broken: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGRVew

Anyway, here are a few things to keep in mind:

- You have to assign the textures to the uniforms **after** you have created the shader pass. Uniforms are cloned for the internal material of `ShaderPass`. That means textures are cloned, too. The respective `needsUpdate` flag is not set correctly if you load the texture before the material creation.
- As mentioned by @Marquizzo, your texture are blocked for security reasons. I've added some textures from the `three.js` repo for test purposes.
- The following line of code is not necessary since uv coordinates are provided with the geometry. It's not necessary to compute them on-the-fly like shadertoy does. Just use the varying `vUv` in the fragment shader.

  ```
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
  ```
- For such simple one-pass shaders, it's not necessary to use `EffectComposer`. Try to use an approach similar to this official [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shader).
- You always have to ensure that the example files like `ShaderPass` or `EffectComposer` match the `three.js` version in your code. I've changed this in the codepen in order to remove all deprecation warnings.

Comment: Do you know if the removal of the `renderTarget` parameter from `WebGLRenderer.render()` in r102 has affected the `EffectComposer` examples?

Comment: We updated the examples so they should all work without warnings.

Comment: Ah, I thought so. It looks like the Codepen above is using [this version from cdn.rawgit](https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js), which looks to be the older one compared to [this newer version from the examples](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js)

Comment: Yep, the versions of the files in the original codepen do not match.

Comment: I'm still a complete noob at this, but thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I fixed the effect, just for you to know what I wanted to achieve !
https://codepen.io/LDB95/pen/YgQxpX